# SHA certificate fingerprints | Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I got SHA-256, SHA1 fingerprint using this command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\asd\.android\debug.keystore" -alias android
debugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Now, I want to get SHA-256, SHA1 again.
when I use above command again it ask

```
Enter keystore password:
```

How to get SHA-256, SHA1 fingerprint ?

Comment: use 'android' as password

Answer (score 0):

Use 'android' as password. Since you set the password as android in the command you executed.